# Change DIV contents using jQuery when link clicked

Tags: jquery, html

Thank you, in advance, for those who answer =)
I'm trying to switch between divs when i click the links with the respective class (as follow on the code bellow).
It works for the first link, but not for the others.
What am I doing wrong, and what other 'function' can i use to do this?

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".content").hide();

$("#cont").click(function() {
if ($(this).hasClass("info")){ $("#info").slideToggle(500); }
if ($(this).hasClass("gallery")){ $("#gallery").slideToggle(500); }
if ($(this).hasClass("projects")){ $("#projects").slideToggle(500); }
if ($(this).hasClass("contacts")){ $("#contacts").slideToggle(500); }
    // $(".content").slideToggle(500);
});

});
```

HTML

```
<?php $type = $_GET['o']; ?>

<div class="sidebar1">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a id="cont" class="info" href="#">Info</a></li>
      <li><a id="cont" class="gallery" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      //<li><a id="cont" class="projects" href="index.php?o=projects">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a id="cont" class="contacts"  href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
  <div class="content" id="info">
    <h1>Info</h1>
    <p>Info content ...</p>
</div>
<div class="content" id="gallery">
    <h1>Gallery</h1>
    <p>Gallerycontent ...</p>
</div> <!-- it's the same for the other links -->
```

On a later note..
How can I do something similar to this, using the links to say what '$type' to include, using only one 'content' div?
'Projects' link is commented as example.

```
<div class="content">
    <?php include($type . ".txt"); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check Ids and class names.

Answer (score 1):

The classes in your HTML code should be the same as those in JQuery code :

```
gallery != galerias,
```

etc.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake.
Apart from that, with the classes named the same, it still just work for the first link.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#cont').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var idToSlide = $(this).attr('class');
  $('#' + idToSlide).slideToggle(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to fix it is this:

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar1">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a class="cont info" href="#">Info</a></li>
      <li><a class="cont gallery" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      //<li><a class="cont projects" href="index.php?o=projects">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a class="cont contacts" href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
  <div class="content" id="info">
    <h1>Info</h1>
    <p>Info content ...</p>
</div>
<div class="content" id="gallery">
    <h1>Gallery</h1>
    <p>Gallerycontent ...</p>
</div> <!-- it's the same for the other links -->
```

jQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".content").hide();

$(".cont").click(function() {
if ($(this).hasClass("info")){ $("#info").slideToggle(500); }
if ($(this).hasClass("gallery")){ $("#gallery").slideToggle(500); }
if ($(this).hasClass("projectos")){ $("#projectos").slideToggle(500); }
if ($(this).hasClass("contactos")){ $("#contactos").slideToggle(500); }
    // $(".content").slideToggle(500);
});
});
```

All I've done was to change cont id to cont class. Remember that two or more elements can't have the same ID, so only the first element will be considered.

Ah! And as lmsteffan told, in JQUERY you're using "galerias" and in HTML "gallery". Please check it.

Comment: That worked just fine. Thanks =)
    Regarding the last part of my question, any ideas?
    I want to have just one .content div where i load the content depending on the selected link.
    Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be this work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content").hide();

    $("#cont").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("info")){ $(".info").slideToggle(500); }
    if ($(this).hasClass("gallery")){ $(".gallery").slideToggle(500); }
    if ($(this).hasClass("projects")){ $(".projectos").slideToggle(500); }
    if ($(this).hasClass("contacts")){ $(".contactos").slideToggle(500); }
        // $(".content").slideToggle(500);
    });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for u:

```
  $(document).ready(function () { 
            $(".content").hide();
        });


function test(Idpassing) {
            var clsname = Idpassing[0].id;


            if (clsname == "cont") { $("#info").slideToggle(500); }
            if (clsname == "gal") { $("#gallery").slideToggle(500); }
            if (clsname =="projectos") { $("#projectos").slideToggle(500); }
            if (clsname == "conta") { $("#Contacts").slideToggle(500); }
        }

        <div class="sidebar1">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li><a id="cont" class="info" href="#" onclick="test($('#cont'))">Info</a></li>
              <li><a id="gal" class="gallery" href="#" onclick="test($('#gal'))">Gallery</a></li>
              <li><a id="conta" class="contacts"  href="#" onclick="test($('#conta'))">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
          <div class="content" id="info">
            <h1>Info</h1>
            <p>Info content ...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="gallery">
            <h1>Gallery</h1>
            <p>Gallerycontent ...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="Contacts">
            <h1>Contacts</h1>
            <p>Contactscontent ...</p>
        </div>
```

Send the data using id

Answer (score 0):

Rui,

I would do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <h1 id="content-title"></h1>
    <p id="content-text"></p>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".cont").click(function() {
if ($(this).hasClass("info")){
   $("#content-title").text("Your text goes here"); //Set some text in content-title element
   $("#content-text").text("Your text goes here"); //Set some text in content-text element 
   $(".content").slideToggle(500); //Show the content element class

}
});
```

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wCMn/)
    I know I'm being a pain, but how do i toggle between divs? => One of them is open, and when i click another, that opens and the current closes.
  Thanks