# Change div content on ImageClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, i'm working on this: http://silviucazacu.com/cold and i want to change the content(image&player) when i click on the images in the left.
I want to have all on the same page, but hidden and on image click to appear on center.

Comment: Please post a code snippet, either here or via jsfiddle...

Comment: "Change the content of **X** when **Y** is clicked" is one of **the most** frequently asked questions known to web-kind. Here is [Change DIV content...when link clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158444/)

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more precise ?
It's kind of easy to do it, you should have researched it.

Edit your img tag like

```
<img onclick="someJScodethatwillbeexecutedonclicked"></img>
```